# Java: How to convert mp3 to a wav clip without external programs

Tags: java, audio, mp3, wav, clip

I have a java program that plays .wav files by putting them into Clips. I wanted to know if there was a way (without JLayer or any external libraries) to convert an mp3 file into a wav file that I could put into a Clip? Thanks

Comment: MP3 is a proprietary codec.  There is no native library to either decode or encode MP3s in Java.  Without an external library, you would have to write your own (which I don't think is possible since, like I said the MP3 format isn't really publicly available).

Comment: Try to look into `AudioSystem.isConversionSupported`. More information on converting audio files in the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/converters.html).